# aspnet core dependency injection with IOptions in startup

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection

What is going on gang?

I am looking for a proper and clean way of injecting configuration into my classes using the IOptions package. Currently, I am registering all the configuration object in one place and everything is just fine. The problem is with some classes that I need to register in the startup method.

The initial method implementation looks like this: (extension method)

```
public static void RegisterHttpClients(this IServiceCollection services, AppSettings appSettings)
{
    services.AddHttpClient<IPdfService, PdfService>(
        httpClient => httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("PdfApiKey", appSettings.PdfApiKey));
}
```

This `AppSettings` object I am also injecting into other classes using IOptions so would like to somehow reuse the object from there instead of having to get same object from json again like that:

```
var appSettings = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Get<AppSettings>();
services.RegisterHttpClients(appSettings);
```

In other words - I already have the thing registered with `services.Configure<AppSettings>(configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));` so would kind of like to piggy-back on this if possible.

Any thoughts/suggestions for possible directions on how to configure this?

EDIT: (added JSON and AppSettings files)

```
public class AppSettings 
{
    public string PdfApiKey {get; set;}
    public string AnotherProperty {get; set;}
}
```

```
{
    "AppSettings": {
        "PdfApiKey": "SomeKey",
        "AnotherProperty": "HollyTheCow"
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show your `AppSettings` class and json

Comment: Added. The thing is that the rest of the application gets the settings just fine so the configuration parsing is correct for sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by registering your options with Configure (which you've done), then using the second overload to `AddHttpClient()` to get the registered options from the DI container (Service Locator pattern). Note I've used `IServiceProvider.GetRequiredService`, but you can use `IServiceProvider.GetService()?.Value` if it's an optional setting.

```cs
services.Configure<AppSettings>(_configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));

services.AddHttpClient<YourService>((serviceProvider, config) => {
    var settings = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<AppSettings>>().Value;

    config.BaseAddress = new Uri(settings.BaseUri);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code has no any error and will run successfully

There may be many `appSetting.json` files on your project.

Check the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`variable on your project.

> **Right click on your project > Properties > Debug > Environment variables**

if `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` is set on **Development** `IConfiguration` read data from
`appSettings.development.json` and you should add `AppSettigs` json in `appSettings.development.json`

if `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` is set on **Production** `IConfiguration` read data from
`appSettings.production.json` and you should add `AppSettigs` json in `appSettings.production.json`

if you want `IConfiguration` read data from **appSetting.json** delete both **appSettings.development.json** and **appSettings.production.json** file.

in this case `IConfiguration` by default read and bind data from **appSetting.json**

***Another options***

You can config your `IConfiguration` to load data dynamically from
`appSettings.json` like this

```cs
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    this.configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

Comment: That's cool. Thanks. The thing is still a bit unclear how to avoid secondary call to json for cofiguration (Dont like the "AppSettings" strings hardcoded in several places). In this case in the RegisterHttpClients I have to pass in the AppSettings, which I am only registering through options binding. So basically I have services.Configure<AppSettings>(configuration.GetSection("AppSettings")) in one place and var appSettings = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Get<AppSettings>(); in another (note that I have to use the "AppSettings" string twice.